# Problemas com SQLiteHelper

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Ola, tenho um projeto de cadastro e estou com problemas na leitura do SQLiteHelper, o app só roda sem ele, quando tento usar dá erro, o aplicativo desliga, se alguém puder me ajudar a encontrar onde está o erro agradeço. 
 segue o código, se alguém puder me ajudar...
Obrigado.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static SQLiteHelper mSQLiteHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    mSQLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper( this, "RECORDDB.sqlite",null,1 );
    mSQLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RECORD(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, age VARCHAR, phone VARCHAR, image BLOB ");
```

Classe List

```
public class RecordListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView mListView;
ArrayList<Model> mList;
RecordListAdapter mAdapter = null;
ImageView imageViewIcon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_record_list );

    mListView = findViewById( R.id.listView );
    mList = new ArrayList<>(  );
    mAdapter = new RecordListAdapter( this, R.layout.row, mList );
    mListView.setAdapter( mAdapter );

    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.mSQLiteHelper.getData( "SELECT * FROM RECORD" );
    mList.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id       = cursor.getInt   ( 0 );
        String name  = cursor.getString( 1 );
        String age   = cursor.getString( 2 );
        String phone = cursor.getString( 3 );
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob  ( 4 );
        mList.add( new Model( id, name, age, phone, image ) );

    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    if(mList.size()==0){
        Toast.makeText( this,"No record found...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
    mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,  final int position, long id) {

        final CharSequence[] items = {"Update","Delete"};

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder( RecordListActivity.this );

        dialog.setTitle( "Choose an action" );
        dialog.setItems( items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        if (i ==0) {
        Cursor c = MainActivity.mSQLiteHelper.getData( "SELECT id FROM RECORD" );
        ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
        arrID.add( c.getInt( 0 ) );
                    }
        showDialogUpdate( RecordListActivity.this, arrID.get( position ) );
                }
        if (i==1){
        Cursor c = MainActivity.mSQLiteHelper.getData( "SELECT id FROM RECORD" );
        ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<Integer>(  );
        while (c.moveToNext()){
        arrID.add (c.getInt(0  ));
                    }
       showDialogDelete(arrID.get( position ));
                }
                }
            }) ;
       dialog.show();
       return true;
        }
    } );
}

     btnUpdate.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                MainActivity.mSQLiteHelper.updateData(
                        edtName .getText().toString().trim(),
                        edtAge  .getText().toString().trim(),
                        edtPhone.getText().toString().trim(),
                        MainActivity.imageViewToByte( imageViewIcon ),
                        position
                );
                //dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Update Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
            catch (Exception error) {
                Log.e( "Update error", error.getMessage() );
            }
            updateRecordList();
        }
    });
}

 private void updateRecordList() {
    Cursor cursor = MainActivity.mSQLiteHelper.getData( "SELECT * FROM RECORD" );
    mList.clear();
    while ( cursor.moveToNext() ){
        int id = cursor.getInt         ( 0 );
        String name  = cursor.getString( 1 );
        String age   = cursor.getString( 2 );
        String phone = cursor.getString( 3 );
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob  ( 4 );

        mList.add( new Model(id, name, age, phone, image  ) );
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Classe SQLiteHelper

```
public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

SQLiteHelper(Context context,
             String name,
             SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
             int version){
    super(context, name, factory, version );
}

public void queryData(String sql) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL( sql );
}

public void insertData(String name, String age, String phone, byte[] image ){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO RECORD VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement( sql );
    statement.clearBindings();

    statement.bindString( 1,name );
    statement.bindString( 2,age );
    statement.bindString( 3,phone );
    statement.bindBlob  ( 4,image  );

    statement.executeInsert();
}

public void updateData(String name, String age, String phone, byte[] image, int id){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "UPDATE RECORD SET name=?, age=?, phone=?, image=? WHERE id=?";
    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement( sql );

    statement.bindString( 1, name  );
    statement.bindString( 2, age   );
    statement.bindString( 3, phone );
    statement.bindBlob  ( 4, image );
    statement.bindDouble( 5, (double)id );

    statement.execute();
    database.close();
}

public void deleteData (int id){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "DELETE FROM RECORD WHERE id=?";
    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement( sql );
    statement.clearBindings();
    statement.bindDouble( 1, (double)id );
    statement.execute();
    database.close();
}

public Cursor getData(String sql){
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    return database.rawQuery( sql, null );
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
}
}
```

LogCat

```
07-04 14:31:13.361 2081-2081/com.daniel.listview_cadastro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.daniel.listview_cadastro/com.daniel.listview_cadastro.Produtos}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Can't downgrade database from version 2 to 1
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.onDowngrade(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:361)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:255)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
    at com.daniel.listview_cadastro.SQLiteHelper.queryData(SQLiteHelper.java:19)
    at com.daniel.listview_cadastro.Produtos.onCreate(Produtos.java:50)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
```

Acho que o erro esta nestas linhas abaixo mais não sei como corrigir

```
    at com.daniel.listview_cadastro.SQLiteHelper.queryData(SQLiteHelper.java:19)
    at com.daniel.listview_cadastro.Produtos.onCreate(Produtos.java:50)
```

Comment: Provavelmente é um erro de SQL que está causando isso. Se vc abrir o Logcat do Android Studio vai conseguir ver o StackTrace. Edita sua publicação e cola essa mensagem para ajudar a identificar o erro.

Comment: Achei o erro  nessa linha mSQLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper( this, "RECORDDB.sqlite",null,1 ); coloquei como versão 1 e no Gradie esta versão 2, foi so´passar para versão 2 e deu certo.